# What to use in plsr and plsrglm to choose optimal number of components

Tags: r, components

I am using partial least square (PLS) regression in R, using the packages pls and plsRglm. I generate a dataframe as below, and used the two packages to perform PLS.

I chosed the optimal number of components with RMSEP in package pls, while with BIC with package plsRglm. Below are the R script.

```
x1 <- as.numeric(round(runif(10,-40,40),2))
x2 <- as.numeric(round(x1*1.4+60,2))
x3 <- as.numeric(round(runif(10,20,60),2))
x4 <- as.numeric(round(x2*0.9+60,2))
x5 <- as.numeric(round(x2*x3*0.9+60,2))
x6 <- as.numeric(round(x2*x3*x4*x5/1000000,2))

y <-  as.numeric(round(runif(10,50,150),2))

df <- data.frame(y,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)


library(pls)
# plsr, RMSEP
mod.plsr <- plsr(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, data=df, 
             ncomp=5, validation="CV")

## delta vector contains RMSEP differences  
err.CV = c()
for (i in 1:10) {err.CV[i] = RMSEP(mod.plsr)$val[i*2+1]}   
delta = err.CV[1:9] - err.CV[2:10]    
comp.plsr = min(which(delta<0.05)) 
plot(RMSEP(mod.plsr),legendpos="topright", main="")

## mixed model regression coefficients
mod.plsr.opt = plsr(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, data=df, 
                ncomp = comp.plsr)

coef(mod.plsr.opt)

, , 1 comps

           y
x1 4.324635e-05
x2 6.054166e-05
x3 3.218208e-05
x4 5.449111e-05
x5 4.142277e-03
x6 4.653091e-03




library(plsRglm)
# plsrglm, BIC
mod.plsrglm = plsRglm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, data=df, 
                  nt=5, model="pls")

# use BIC to determine optimal number of components 
comp.plsrglm = which(mod.plsrglm$InfCrit[,2] ==    min(mod.plsrglm$InfCrit[,2]))-1

# refit model and extract beta coefficients from the optimal model
mod.plsrglm.opt = plsRglm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, data=df, 
                      nt=comp.plsr, model="pls")

mod.plsrglm.opt$Coeffs

               [,1]
Intercept -4.422569e+05
x1        -3.150225e+03
x2        -2.355536e+03
x3         4.523422e+00
x4         5.120661e+03
x5        -1.490321e-01
x6         7.920704e-02
```

I have several questions on these two different packages.

1) Can I produce RMSEP in plsRglm? Can I plot it as I did in plsr?

2) Should I used AIC or BIC in plsRglm to determine the optimal number of component?

3) Why the two packages are giving quite different results? Why plsRglm is giving an intercept coefficient but it is not in plsr?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

3) try

```
coef(mod.plsr.opt, intercept = TRUE)
```

to get intercept in 'pls' package.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide a minimum example that can be run.